# Canvas' drawBitmap method causes bad performance after scaling

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, draw, scaling

I'm trying to create a simple translational movement for a Bitmap object. I'm doing this by creating a canvas and passing a framebuffer to it, which had previously been initialized to a resolution of 1080/1920. I then proceeding to draw a bitmap with a call to canvas' method drawBitmap() like so:

```
this.canvas = new Canvas(frameBuffer);

...

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, destinationRect, paint);
```

In a different thread which is set as the Content View for the main activity I'm scaling the framebuffer to fit the actual screen size and then draw it with all its contents with these lines:

```
Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
canvas.getClipBounds(dstRect);

...

canvas.drawBitmap(framebuffer, null, dstRect, paint);
holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

This results in very poor performance, both measuring manually with delta time and by monitoring with the Android Studio tools. Even visually you can see a trailing after the bitmap accompanied with very low fps.

I can't seem to find the cause of this, but I suspect that the scaling process that drawBitmap executes implicitly is doing something heavy. I tried changing the filter settings without success. I also doubt that I should head for openGL for this simple need.

Should I use bitmaps with different sizes and decide on runtime what size is the closest to my need or is there a more straightforward solution to this problem?

EDIT:
Here's how I gain a few more frames per second with the matrix.postScale() method:

```
        int width = framebuffer.getWidth();
        int height = framebuffer.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) game.size.x) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) game.size.y) / height;
        // create a matrix for the manipulation
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // resize the bit map
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        // recreate the new Bitmap
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(framebuffer, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

        canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#013501"));
        canvas.drawBitmap(resizedBitmap, null, dstRect, paint);
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

Comment: I did, with it I gain around 15 fps, and without fps drops to 3

Comment: with and without what?

Comment: With the matrix.postScale() method

Comment: so when you use **scaled** matrix you have 15 fps and if you use it without `postScale` its 3?

Comment: thats about right, yes

Comment: if its faster, whats your problem then?

Comment: sorry, I didn't explain it better. It IS faster, but it still has 20 fps and looks bad. And actually I tried it right now and sometimes it gets to 10 fps with the postScale, so it's not good. How would I go about supporting different screen sizes without scaling anyways?

Comment: I added the code with the call to postScale in my original question

Comment: remove `Bitmap.createBitmap` from a drawing loop, its extremely expensive, just use original bitmap (not resized in any way) and use scaled `Matrix` for a drawing

Comment: I didn't realize that. Thanks. 
Is there a way to directly put the scaled matrix to a canvas.drawBitmap?

Comment: directly put? meaning what?

Comment: It's solved! Thank you. 

By the way, I still see a bit of trailing, could it be a filtering issue?

Comment: i have no idea what you really mean...

Comment: Well, I gained back the fps but its still looking crappy. I don't know what could it be this time.

Comment: post your current code then